# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with Discord JDA 350+ threads

Tags: java, multithreading, discord, out-of-memory, discord-jda

so I'll try to explain my problem as well as I can. Currently I'm working on a quite decent scale program. However I've never worked with this many threads, as said 350+. It's currently giving me an out of memory error, however I already tried various options:

- adding the -Xss parameter
- adding other parameters I could find on [this website](https://docs.gigaspaces.com/latest/production/production-jvm-tuning.html)
- further I've tried to edit the stacksize and user limits

[image]

The errors I get for an out of memory leak problem are put down below.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:804)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.start(Http2Connection.java:515)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.start(Http2Connection.java:499)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.startHttp2(RealConnection.java:299)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:288)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:169)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:264)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.Requester.execute(Requester.java:200)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.Requester.execute(Requester.java:140)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.Requester.execute(Requester.java:123)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.ratelimit.BotRateLimiter$Bucket.run(BotRateLimiter.java:468)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

```
[111,061s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
Exception in thread "Thread-365" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:804)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1583)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:346)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:562)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:705)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable.applyAndAckSettings(Http2Connection.java:738)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable.settings(Http2Connection.java:710)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader.readSettings(Http2Reader.java:289)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader.nextFrame(Http2Reader.java:141)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader.readConnectionPreface(Http2Reader.java:80)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable.execute(Http2Connection.java:607)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Where as I found that no matter what I do the thread stack size always appears to be 1024.

[image]

I currently run this .jar file from a VPS with the following specs:

- unlimited traffic
- 32GB RAM
- 600GB SSD
- 16 cores

My question would be, is there a way to edit this thread stack size?

Another separate question: Whenever I use -Xss2g it does show me it goes over the limit, but is there a way to edit this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to figure it out.

The provider where I hosted, which I will leave unknown to the name, limited the amount of threads I could run at the same time to 1300 threads. Because they had this at a fixed amount, I kept running into problems with my threads, which the errors are also shown in the question.

Because they locked this amount, I was limited to my options, so I decided to switch provider instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to configure JDA and change defaults to reduce the memory footprint. Make sure you also use the latest version of JDA (which is currently 4.2.0_252).

Read the FAQ: [How can I reduce the memory footprint of my bot?](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/10%29-FAQ#how-can-i-reduce-the-memory-footprint-of-my-bot)

Comment: I already tracked down the memory my bot used and it was mainly JDA that only took up 140MB which is not that much memory in the heap space. I managed to figure out the answer to my own question, but it is indeed a valid statement that you'd need to upgrade with mavencentral to 4.2.0_252, so don't use jcenter. Thanks for the help Minn